# MS Access: Hiding a sub form when Focus is lost for any other controls but itself

Tags: forms, ms-access, lost-focus

I am developing a MS access database (2016).

I have a main form (named **MF**) which has a big number of controls including one subform. This subform named **SF** and it is related to two of the controls on the **MF**. These controls named **C1** and **C2**.

When **MF** is loaded, **SF** is not visible.

When **C1** or **C2** got focus, **SF** visibility is set to **`True`**.

Now what I need is:

1- To set **SF** visibility to **`False`** once **C1** or **C2** lost focus for other controls except for **SF**.

2- To set **SF** visibility to **`False`** Once it loses focus for any controls on **MF** except for **C1** and **C2**.

It seemed simple at the begining and it seemed straight forward, but it is not.

I used:

```
Private Sub C1_GotFocus()
    Me.SF.Visible = True
End Sub

Private Sub C2_GotFocus()
    Me.SF.Visible = True
End Sub

Private Sub C1_LostFocus()
    Me.SF.Visible = False
End Sub

Private Sub C2_LostFocus()
    Me.SF.Visible = False
End Sub

Private Sub SF_LostFocus()
    Me.SF.Visible = False
End Sub
```

Now if **C1** or **C2** loses control for **SF** it disappears and I cannot pick the information I need for **C1** and **C2**.

Also if **SF** loses Focus for **C1** and **C2** it does disappear

It seemed easy to fix that with a few **`if`** statements, however this is not the case.

The problem is that the new control that gains the Focus is NOT predictable by the `LostFocus()` event. Hence, it is hard to do it this way.

I searched the net for a solution and found nothing I can use.

a workaround would be to omit the `LostFocus()` events for **C1**, **C2** and **SF** and setting every other single control on **MF** that gains focus to hide **SF**.

While this works as I need, it seems not to be a practical solution.

**Is there a more straight forward and rational way to accomplish this?**

Remember that the Main form has too many controls to be coded this way.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I would consider using the OnCurrent event of MF, which gets fired when a new record is set, or when you move to a new record. I am not sure if C1 or C2 are editable. If they are not then it's simple. If they are, you just need to make sure that both have a value before you set the visibility of SF. The code behind MF should have one function, not bound to any event, with a name like "SetSubformVisibility". In it, check the value of C1 and C2 and show/hide SF accordingly. Make sure to only set the visibility if it is not already that way. for example:

```
If Me.SF.Visible = true THEN Me.SF.Visible = False
```

In this way you are not always setting this as Access will flicker with the way its event model works. In this way, if it runs more than it should, nothing really happens. You can then call this single function in the OnFocus, OnLostFocus, OnCurrent, etc. of the form. Depending on the editability of C1 and C2, the OnCurrent may be enough.

You may also want to move some logic into SF, such as the OnLoad. You can reference the parent form and programatically change the SF RecordSource as you need to. Using the LinkChild/Master properties of the subform control may be difficult to plumb.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks @DanielG, **C1** and **C2** are editable and they are used to filter **SF** contents. when the required value is shown in **SF** it can be picked up by double clicking on it. The problem is how to keep **SF** subform visible **only** if the active control is **C1**, **C2** or **SF** itself. Otherwise it should be hidden. The problem occurs when  Focus is lost from **C1** or **C2** because losing focus code hides **SF**. How could I tell either **C1** and **C2** not to hide  **SF** if the focus is moving to **SF** itself.

Comment: Would the AfterUpdate event of C1 and C2 work better perhaps? In other words, only if this value has changed should something be done. Also, maybe in your code consider incorporating the Screen.ActiveControl property, and if it is either C1, C2, or SF, short-circuit the hide property?

Comment: Another idea would be to have a button called "Apply Filter" that requeried the subform. If C1 and C2 are unbound filter controls (not bound to a field), maybe let the user enter one or more parameters, and then hit an Apply button. The code behind that button can run your logic in a controlled manner, and two parameters can be applied at once.